# core php: My php script does not accept any request until current request is complete

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest

I have a php script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );  
require_once("user_details.php");

$GLOBALS['woocommerce'] = WC();
getPostData($woocommerce);
function getPostData($woocommerce){
    $user_id;  
    if(isset($_GET['userName'], $_GET['password'])){
   $user = wp_authenticate($_GET['userName'], $_GET['password']);
   if (!is_wp_error($user)){
      if(filter_var($_GET['userName'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $user_id=getUserByEmail($_GET['userName']);
    }
    else {
   $user_id=getUserByUserName($_GET['userName']);
    }
   $user_info=getUserInfo($user_id);
    $user_info= json_encode(array($user_info));
   echo $user_info;
}
else{
    $error = $user->get_error_message();
     echo '{"RESULT":"ERROR_INVALID_LOGIN_DETAILS"}';
}
}
else{
echo '{"RESULT":"_GET_ERROR"}';
}
}
?>
```

I am unable to call this script from multiple android/ios devices.. only the first request is handled while others wait in queue forever... someone please help me how to handle this!